# Can't wire-up Click event for dynamically created Buttons in a GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, events, gridview, iteration

I'm dynamically creating the templates for a `GridView` and data binding it in my ASP.NET web app. I've added the header column templates as well as a column of buttons. The trouble I'm having is that wiring up click events for the buttons never seem to fire. I've tried grabbing the buttons (after the `DataBind()` method) in multiple ways, but nothing seems to fire when the button is clicked.

**Note**: the `GridView` is inside an `ASP:UpdatePanel` and AJAX accordion pane (ToolkitScriptManager on Site.Master).

Here's the relevant portion of the aspx page (simplified)...

```
<ajaxToolkit:AccordionPane ID="accordionSelfRegisteredUsers" runat="server">
    <Header>Find All Self-Registered Users</Header>
    <Content>
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="updatepnlSelfRegisteredUsers" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <div id="divFixedHeaderSelfRegisteredUsers"></div>
                <div id="divSelfRegisteredUsers">
                    <asp:GridView ID="gridviewSelfRegisteredUsers" runat="server"
                        AutoGenerateColumns="False" />
                </div>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </Content>
</ajaxToolkit:AccordionPane>
```

Here's the page's C# code.

One way...

```
List<Button> gvConfirmButtons = new List<Button>();
foreach (GridViewRow row in gridviewSelfRegisteredUsers.Rows)
{
    foreach (Control c in row.Controls)
    {
        if (typeof(DataControlFieldCell) != c.GetType())
        {
            continue;
        }
        foreach (Control cf in c.Controls)
        {
            if (typeof(Button) == cf.GetType())
            {
                gvConfirmButtons.Add((Button)cf);
            }
        }
    }
}
foreach (Button b in gvConfirmButtons)
{
    b.Click += new EventHandler(btnGVSRUConfirm_Click);
}
```

And another I tried...

```
foreach (GridViewRow row in gridviewSelfRegisteredUsers.Rows)
{
    foreach (Control c in row.Controls)
    {
        if (typeof(DataControlFieldCell) != c.GetType())
        {
            continue;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < gridviewSelfRegisteredUsers.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            //find buttons by client ID
            Button b = (Button)c.FindControl(
                "contentMain_gridviewSelfRegisteredUsers_btnConfirm_" + i);
            b.Click += new EventHandler(btnGVSRUConfirm_Click);
        }
    }
}
```

The buttons are found and I can access them, but the click event from the button never triggers the click event method I have in code.

```
private void btnGVSRUConfirm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}
```

Any thoughts on how I might be messing this up? I have a feeling it's related to the current state of the gridview within the page lifecycle when the button is clicked by the user, but not sure how to proceed.

Comment: When/where in the page life cycle do you run this code that attaches the handlers?

Comment: I have a navigation menu on this page, so it all occurs when the user clicks on that navigation's button to see everything regarding that content.

Comment: I've tried adding both .Attributes["onclick"] and .OnClientClick to point the buttons to a javascript method, and that works. I just can't get it to go to a server-side method in C# with .Click. Any ideas or thoughts of troubleshooting steps to try would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: After more research, I tried something else, but it still didn't work. Others have mentioned that event wire-up needs be done on the page's PreInit or Init instead of after the page is loaded, so I created a List of a lot of Buttons, wired them up, then added them to the GridView later. No dice. It still fails to call the event method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a simular issue a while back when putting an update panel inside a ModalPopup control. Something to do with the __doPostback not being wired-up correctly to the buttons OnClick event. Not sure if it is a bug or what, but this is what I did in the Page_Load event to solve the issue:

```
PostBackOptions opt = new PostBackOptions(this.YourButtonID);
opt.AutoPostBack = true;
opt.ClientSubmit = true;
opt.PerformValidation = true;
opt.RequiresJavaScriptProtocol = true;

// This will put a '__doPostBack()' javascript call on the OnClick 
// event (using above options).
this.YourButtonID.OnClientClick = ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(opt);
```

Hope this solves your issue!